# Add Class to every second element, count from the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a list where I want to add classes to every second element, counting from the first one.

Here's my list

```
<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet"></span>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ul>
```

I want to have it like this:

```
<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet"></span>
  <li class="odd"></li>
  <li class="even"></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li class="odd"></li>
  <li class="even"></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li class="odd"></li>
  <li class="even"></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li class="odd"></li>
  <li class="even"></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li class="odd"></li>
  <li class="even"></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ul>
```

Here's my jQuery Code

```
$(".timeline li:nth-of-type(2n)").addClass('even');
```

It's no problem to add the 'even' classes, but how to add the 'odd' classes? Which selector should I use to count from the first list element?

Comment: If it's only for styling, you can just use native CSS selectors `li:nth-child(odd)` and `li:nth-child(even)` It'll be faster and more efficient than jQuery.

Comment: You should not use direct span or div child in ul. It's semantically wrong html.

Comment: Invalid HTML as `<ul>` can have `<li>` elements as child

Comment: In my answer i achieved your request ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use odd and even selector of jquery like this

```
$( ".timeline li:odd" ).addClass('odd');
$( ".timeline li:even" ).addClass('even');
```

For your requirement you need to first odd and than even so you change this jquery like this

```
$( ".timeline li:odd" ).addClass('even');
$( ".timeline li:even" ).addClass('odd');
```

Comment: Watchout it gives a result with a different order

Comment: Because it's get first li as 0 and it's even so add first element even and than odd

Comment: I don't need an explanation, just saying that he wanted the opposite order ^^

Answer (score 2):

Or JUST this

```
document.body.querySelectorAll(".timeline li").forEach(function(node,i){
   node.classList.add(i % 2?"even":"odd");
})
```

Comment: I like the efficiency of this. A jQuery version could be `$(".timeline li").each(function(i){ $(this).addClass(i%2?"even":"odd"); })`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:
Iterate through the elements matching ".timeline li" and add the correct class whether its index is even or not.

```
$(".timeline li").each((index, el) => $(el).addClass(index % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'));
```

Comment: While this may answer the question a small explanation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: While I love arrow functions, it's worth mentioning they are unsupported in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply add `prev()` method to your code:

```js
$(".timeline li:nth-of-type(2n)").addClass('even').prev().addClass('odd');
```

```css
.even{
  color:red;
}
.odd{
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet">Span</span>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
  <div class="clearfix">Div</div>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
  <div class="clearfix">Div</div>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
  <div class="clearfix">Div</div>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
  <div class="clearfix">Div</div>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
  <div class="clearfix">Div</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(".timeline li:nth-of-type(2n)").addClass('even');
```

to:

```
    $(".timeline li:nth-child(even)").addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to style elements you can target them using css

```
.timeline li:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
    background: red;
}
.timeline li:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add odd/even class like the below example.
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.listul li:even').addClass('even');
  $('ul.listul li:odd').addClass('odd');
});
```

```css
li.even {
  color: #000;
}

li.odd {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listul">
  <li>list1</li>
  <li>list2</li>
  <li>list3</li>
  <li>list4</li>
  <li>list5</li>
  <li>list6</li>
</ul>
```